# I set the width of an element in Hubspot... now I can't center it

Tags: hubspot

I hate hubspot with my whole soul.

When I set the width of a module... it moves over to the left.

Nothing in the CSS changes it so I can center it.

Any help?

Comment: I want to set the width of the white box to like 300px... when I do it jumps over to the left. WTF? 

http://info.augsburgfortress.org/-temporary-slug-23a7ef74-b2b2-481d-8dbe-6ab6c85a9847?hs_preview=HHkEnLcf-4102500596

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the element is floated to the left.  This should help:
    .row-fluid > .your-element {width: 300px; margin: 0 auto!important; float: none!important;}